# Do Muslims worship the same deity as Christians?

Tags: quran, allah, christianity

Christians pray to prophet Jesus, his mother Mary and even to Jibril.

Additionally Quran mentions case of Allah's name being called in synagogues and churches.

> For had it not been that Allah checks one set of people by means of another, **monasteries, churches, synagogues, and mosques, wherein the Name of Allah is mentioned much would surely have been pulled down**. Verily, Allah will help those who help His (Cause). Truly, Allah is All-Strong, All-Mighty. Quran 22:40

I have confusion because of above verse. Do muslims really worship same deity as Christians?